# VSCode typescript not inferring types (rarely)

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

In the past couple of weeks I've ran into some cases where types aren't being inferred. This is happening rarely, but I never ran into it until recently.

For example,

```
const extList = productExtensionResArray[index].productExtendList
```

If I hover my mouse over the `.productExtendList` part it shows the proper type for it, but if I hover my mouse over the `extList` part it says it's `any`. This seems like a pretty straight forward type to infer, but it's just not doing it. 99% of the time it's working fine and inferring all my types, but every once in a while it just sets something to `any`, and I'm not sure what the conditions are for this to happen. I've tried reloading the project, restarting the TS server, and restarting VSCode. If I open the same code in WebStorm the type is inferred without issue.

Is anyone else experiencing this issue? Any known solutions?

tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "rootDir": "./",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "noEmit": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"]
}
```

Comment: Sometimes VSCode bugs.
I had same issue. I fix it with 2 methods:
1. Ctrl+Shift+P -> Reload window
2. If broken type is coming from another file I open that file and hover over the thing that is broken. Sometimes I have to leave that file open, because if I close it, types break again :)

Answer (score 0):

My situation was a bit different, where all of my variables were being inferred as `any` type.

What solved it for me was running `npm i --save-dev @types/react`,

### My situation details

The lack of inferences wasn't happening prior to me creating a tsconfig file (I used the `npx tsc --init` default config settings)

I created it to add the `jsx` flag, and I'm not sure what the config settings were without the tsconfig file created. But after creating, all my inferences broke.

Installing @types/react fixed it, restoring the correct inferencing behavior I had before creating my tsconfig.